# How to add an existing Xml string into a XElement

Tags: .net, xml, xelement

How to add an existing Xml string into a XElement?

This code

```
        var doc = new XDocument(
            new XElement("results", "<result>...</result>")
        );
```

of course produces this

```
  <results>&lt;result&gt;&lt;/result&gt;</results>
```

but I need this

```
  <results><result>...</result></results>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68482667/109941

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This should work:

```
var xmlString = "<result>sometext</result>";
var xDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("results", XElement.Parse(xmlString)));
```

Comment: Excellent! I didn't look at class methods. Thank you very much!

Comment: XElement.Parse(xmlString)

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Sani Singh Huttunen put me on the right track, but it only allows one *result* element in the *results* element.

```
var xmlString = "<result>sometext</result><result>alsotext</result>";
```

fails with the System.Xml.XmlException

> There are multiple root elements.

I solved this by moving the *results* element to the string literal

```
var xmlString = "<results><result>sometext</result><result>alsotext</result></results>";
```

so that it had only one root element and then added the parsed string directly to the parent element, like this:

```
parent.Add(XElement.Parse(xmlString));
```

Answer (score 1):

See my answer on [Is there an XElement equivalent to XmlWriter.WriteRaw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723146/is-there-an-xelement-equivalent-to-xmlwriter-writeraw/21098659#21098659)

Essentially, replace a placeholder for the content *only if you know it's already valid XML*.

```
var d = new XElement(root, XML_PLACEHOLDER);
var s = d.ToString().Replace(XML_PLACEHOLDER, child);
```

This method may also be faster than parsing it with `XElement.Parse`.