# C# Xelement to string - converts tags to &lt and &gt

Tags: c#, xml

I am creating some XML using XElement and I then need to convert that XElement into a string to insert into a file.

The problem is that the XML elements are being converted `<example>` to `&ltexample&gt`. This isn't a huge surprise but I don't want this to happen. I need the string exactly as is with the symbols in tact.

Is there any way of avoiding this please?

This is the creation of my Element and the subsequent cast to string:

```
XElement markup = new XElement("xref", new XAttribute("xrefid", value), string.Empty);

string xmlMarkUp = markup.ToString(); //converts the XML to &gt and &lt WHICH I DON'T WANT
```

Comment: *Why* don't you want it to happen? And are you actually only talking about attribute values? (It doesn't help that we don't know what's in `tag` - a [mcve] would make it easier to help you.)

Comment: I've just noticed it deleted the markup i write in the question...hence it appearing a bit vague. No it's not attributes, they are fine as they obviously don't contain less than or more than symbols. It's the element tags themselves.

Comment: Not sure to understand ; you say you don't want **&lt;** and **&gt;** but the code shown seem to imply that `convertToString` is actually meant to do that exact thing

Comment: The comment in the example above meant that this is the result....not what i want it to do. I've edited it.

Comment: Why don't you create a [mcve] which *actually* demonstrates the problem? If you're passing in text that's already actually XML, you should probably just parse that first with `XElement.Parse`.

Comment: I've edited it again to make it as clear as i possibly can.

Comment: As has been said, you need to *demonstrate* the problem. Read the linked content for [mcve]. Your current code, when run with some value for `value` is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W7CMvN) and doesn't show any escaping of angle brackets.

Comment: Are you looking for [How to add an existing Xml string into a XElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414561/how-to-add-an-existing-xml-string-into-a-xelement)?

Answer (score 0):

`XElement markup = new XElement("xref", new XAttribute("xrefid", value)`

my guess : OP want **value** of attribute tag contains another element ex: 123

answer : there is no solution , cause it will violate XML rule **Entity References**
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp

must always convert "<",">" to "&lt"; and "&gt"; respectively within "".